# Best lower bound

Tags: bounds

How could I find the best lower bound of $E[u((1-a)-max(X-a,0))*1_{X>a}]$, where $u$ is an increasing and concave real function with $u(0)=0$ and $a>0$, knowing only the mean and variance of $X$.

Comment: _Best_ in what sense?

Comment: The greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider two cases:
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\left((u(1-a)-\max(X-a, 0))\mathbf{1}_{X > a}\right) &=\begin{cases}\mathbb{E}(u(1-a) + a - X) \text{ if } X>a\\
0\text{ else}
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}u(1-a) + a - \mu_X\text{ if } X>a\\
0\text{ else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Easy to see that the greatest lower bound then is characterized by the properties of $u$ and $a$.